# Java JPA Foreign Key Reference not being saved

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am learning SpringBoot and trying to create a simple API. Using H2 as the data layer.

My table schema is as follow

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cards;
CREATE TABLE Users(USER_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
              NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
              USERNAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
              PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
              IS_ADMIN BOOL);

insert into Users values(10001,'Administrator', 'admin', 'admin', true);

CREATE TABLE Cards(CARD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
              NUMBER VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
              EXPIRY VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
              CVV INT,
              USER INT,
              foreign key (USER) references Users(USER_ID)
);
```

My CreditCard entity looks like following.

```
package sprintboot;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARDS")
@ApiModel(description = "the Credit Card object")
public class CreditCard {

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The DB ID of card")
    private @Column(name = "CARD_ID") @Id @GeneratedValue Long card_id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Credit card number is mandatory")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The number of credit card", required = true)
    private @Column(name = "NUMBER") String number;

    @NotBlank(message = "Credit card expiry is mandatory")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The expiry of credit card", required = true)
    private @Column(name = "EXPIRY") String expiry;

    @NotNull(message = "Credit card cvv is mandatory")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The cvv of credit card", required = true)
    private @Column(name = "CVV") Integer cvv;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The owner user of credit card")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;

    public CreditCard() {}

    public CreditCard(String number, String expiry, Integer cvv, User user) {
        this.number = number;
        this.expiry = expiry;
        this.cvv = cvv;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{number: " + this.number + ", expiry: " + this.expiry + ", cvv: " + this.cvv + ", user: " + this.user + "}";
    }
}
```

My User entity looks like following

```
package springboot;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@ApiModel(description = "the USER object")
public class User {

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The id of User")
    private @Column(name = "USER_ID") @Id @GeneratedValue Long user_id;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The name of User")
    private @Column(name = "NAME") String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The username of User", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
    private @Column(name = "USERNAME") String username;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The password of User", required = true)
    @ValidPassword(message = "Password is mandatory")
    private @Column(name = "PASSWORD") String password;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The admin status of User")
    private @Column(name = "IS_ADMIN") boolean isAdmin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CreditCard> cards;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, String username, String password, boolean isAdmin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{id: " + this.getUser_id() + ", username: " + this.getUsername() + ", isAdmin: " + this.isAdmin() + "}";
    }
}
```

So a CreditCard will contain a user. A user can contain many CreditCards. The problem i am having is that when i try to save the creditcard record. It throws the following error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.In
validDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into cards (cvv, expiry, number, user_user_id, card_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root
```

cause

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "USER_USER_ID" not found; SQL statement:
insert into cards (cvv, expiry, number, user_user_id, card_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.199.jar:1.4.199]
```

I have tried to search and follow several tutorials but cannot get this to work. Can someone please point out where i am wrong.

The method to save the creditcard entity is as follow.

```
public CreditCard upsertCC(
        CreditCard card,
        String jwtToken
) throws UnauthorizedException {
    User user = this.getUserFromJWTToken(jwtToken);
    log.info(user.toString());
    card.setUser(user);
    this.ccRepo.save(card);
    this.ccRepo.flush();
    card.setUser(null);
    return card;
}
```

Where getUserFromJWTToken method returns a User object from the h2 table.

Any suggestions

Comment: It is clearly saying  `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "USER_USER_ID" not found`. It seems the column mapping is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The exception actually is `Column "USER_USER_ID" not found;`

If you see the query,`insert into cards (cvv, expiry, number, user_user_id, card_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, **user_user_id** is mentioned which is not the column name

So the problem is you have not mentioned the column name as `user` in  `CreditCard` entity. Try the below it will work

#### CHANGE TO BE DONE in, CreditCard.class

```java
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The owner user of credit card")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user") // Added the name attribute
    private User user;
```

If you look at the source code of `@JoinColumn's name attribute` they have clearly mentioned

> - If the join is for an element collection,
> - the join column name is formed as the
> - concatenation of the following: the name of the entity; "_";
> - the name of the referenced primary key column.

### EDIT

For second part, you can directly use JPA's functionality.

```java
List<CreditCard> findByNumberContainingAndUser(String number, User user);
```

Comment: One more question.... When i am writing a query... is the following ok.
        @Query("SELECT card FROM CreditCard card where card.number like :searchTerm and card.user=:user")
        List<CreditCard> findByNumberContaingingSearchTermAndUser(String searchTerm, Long user);

Comment: the upsert logic you are asking ?

Comment: Here i am just trying to find all the records for now given a user and a search term

Comment: That will not work because, User is an object not a Long value, I will Edit and update  the post for the solution

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Avi